# Max possible speed in pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, movement

So a friend and I were discussing speeds in pathfinder. He thought the max speed was about 600 ft per round. I thought there might be more buffs for this though. So how fast could a character built exclusively for speed go?

## Limits

- Speed must be reached using only feats, abilities, and racial traits. No spells allowed and it must be done by a playable race in the core books.
- Any level
- The character may not use items to enhance speed.
- *Core Rulebook* only

Comment: Closely related: [an equivalent question for 3.5](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/14505/3548)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For the Core Rulebook alone, this is actually not to hard to figure out:

### Race

None of the core races has a base speed greater than 30ft. Human is a great choice for the bonus feat.

### Feats

Being Human, we have 11 feats at 19th or 20th level. These are quite simple to assign: We'll put one of those into [Run](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/run---final) and the other 10 into [Fleet](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/fleet---final), which explicitly stacks with itself, for a flat 50ft. untyped bonus to our land speed.

### Class(es)

Among the 11 core classes, Barbarian ([Fast Movement](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian#TOC-Fast-Movement-Ex-), land speed, untyped), Druid ([Wild Shape](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid#TOC-Wild-Shape-Su-), replaces base speed), Cleric ([Travel Domain](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/travel-domain), all speeds untyped), and the Monk ([Fast Movement](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk#TOC-Fast-Movement-Ex-), land speed, enhancement bonus) have class features for increasing their speed that are not spells.

#### Land speed

Land speed is quite difficult to achieve, but note that land speed is not limited by any of the Beast Shape forms, thus requiring fewer druid levels. A 4th level druid can transform into a [Deinonychus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/dinosaur/deinonychus) with 60 ft. base land speed.

It does get a little tricky with the [Polymorph rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Transmutation):

> While under the effects of a polymorph spell, you lose [...] any [...] movement types possessed by your original form. You also lose any class features that depend upon form [...] The GM is the final arbiter [...]

But considering that an awakened deinonychus monk/barbarian would have both Fast Movements, I'll assume our Monk/Barbarian/Druid can keep both them in Wild Shape.

We don't need more than 1 level of Barbarian for Fast Movement, or more than one level of Cleric for Travel Domain. We'll put 12 levels in Monk, for a 40ft. enhancement bonus to speed (level 13 and 14 do not increase our speed). The last 2 levels can be put in druid to increase the duration of our wild shape from 4 to 12 hours.

Our Human Barbarian 1/Cleric 1/Druid 6/Monk 12 now has a land speed of 170 ft. in dinosaur form (12 hours a day), which is quintupled when using the Run action, for a total of 850 ft. of movement per round, which is 96 miles per hour.

#### Fly speed

Flying is actually easier: Let's look at transforming into an Air Elemental using the Elemental Body IV variant:

> Air elemental: As elemental body I except that you gain a +4 size bonus to your Strength, +6 size bonus to your Dexterity, and a +4 natural armor bonus. **You also gain fly 120 feet (perfect).**

This is available at 12th, leaving us with 8 spare levels. Taking 2 levels of Barbarian, for the [Swift Foot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo---rage-powers/swift-foot-ex) rage power, giving a 5ft. enhancement bonus to all speeds, and 1 level of Cleric for [Travel Domain's](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/travel-domain) 10 ft. bonus brings us to a total of 135 ft. while raging (130 otherwise), before feats.

Over all, our Cleric 1/Barbarian 2/Druid 12/X 5 ends up with a fly speed of 185 ft., quintupled when "running", for 925 ft. movement per round, which is about 105 miles per hour.

Comment: I will wait a little longer before selecting this as an answer but otherwise good show.

Comment: @Sunspear25 Waiting was good, I completely forgot the Travel domain at first!