# How can someone travel to a moon that's a realistic distance from the planet?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, travel

Since my D&D world is roughly earthlike, the moon is roughly 150,000–400,000 miles away. So a teleport spell would need a caster level > 1,500 to reach the moon.

Is there a method to travel an infinite distance while staying inside the same plane (not using astral travel, etc...), that could be used to get to this moon?

I'm looking for a method that doesn't involve highly theoretical optimization, [like the "Chuck E. Cheese" build](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/14505), Pun-Pun, or similar exploits. Just game elements designed for that kind of long distance in-world travel.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65441/discussion-on-question-by-deadman1204-how-can-someone-travel-to-a-moon-thats-a).

Comment: Please clarify whether you intend teleport spells to be included in your ban on Astral travel.  Also, do you need the travel to be immediate, and if not, how long is it OK to take?

Comment: Let's get those two points clarified and then we can unhold answering it. Thanks!

Comment: Is *wish* an acceptable candidate, or do you have your own DM reasons to exclude that?

Comment: If you use something that *could* move you across planes but without actually doing so, is that okay? Also, is 'fly' a valid answer and if not why?

Answer (score 8):

### RAW

The base 3.5 SRD includes [Greater Teleport](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/teleportGreater.htm) which :

> functions like teleport, except that there is no range limit and there is no chance you arrive off target.

It's a 7th level spell, though it would clearly work from a RAW perspective. It's *technically* travelling through the Astral plane, but since you're already considering teleport, that kind of technically may not matter for your situation.

### RAW-like

Paizo introduced [Interplanetary Teleport](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/interplanetary-teleport/) for Pathfinder. It's a 9th level spell, but one which is clearly intended for traveling between celestial bodies.

If travel to the moon is expected to be fairly common, some enterprising organization may have set up a handful of [Teleportation Circle](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/teleportationCircle.htm)s to facilitate the journey.

If some organization is backing the PCs on their initial exploration of the moon, perhaps they've built a ship of some sort; the Spelljammer setting is built around using spaceships to travel between planets. If the journey is meant to be boring for the characters, this could all be hand-waved at the table "several long weeks later, you arrive at the moon".

### Anecdotal

Anecdotally, I have heard tell of campaigns that basically treat other planets/moons as different planes and let characters use [Plane Shift](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/planeShift.htm) to move between them (they would also let effects that allow creatures to become attuned to planar traits to have similar effect when traveling between celestial objects). That would give players access to the moon as a 5th level spell (via a Cleric), the same level at which Teleport becomes available. Second-hand though it may be, that sounded like it worked for them.

Comment: Teleportation involves the astral plane and is not a valid answer to the question.

Comment: I read that as a prohibition against plane shifting to the Astral plane and using planar trait shenanigans to effectively reduce the distance.

Comment: I gave this an edit to mention the technicality so the reader has that information, but also put it in context with an asker who appears to not/might not mind that technicality.

Comment: You could always just chain *Plane Shift* should the moon not be a separate plane.